# WP8 Speech gets cut off, i.e. it speaks only the end of the sentence

Tags: windows-phone-8, text-to-speech

I have an app that will retrieve a value from a webservice and announce the result.
However, it seemed that the speech will only say the last few words.  I do not think it is due to the webservice as the same issue happens even if I set it to speak a fixed sentence.

For example, I may receive the speech "lots left at XYZ" for the below.

Any ideas?

```
    private async Task Speak(ObservableCollection<CarPark> rs)
    {
        if (rs.Count == 1)
        {
            await Speak(string.Format("There are {0} lots left at {1}", rs[0].lots.ToString(), rs[0].development.ToString()));
        }
    }
    ...
    public async Task Speak(string text)
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer tts = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        await tts.SpeakTextAsync(text);
    }

private async Task CollectCarPark(string Development)
 {
 ObservableCollection<CarPark> rs = new ObservableCollection<CarPark>();
 HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
 rs = await httpClient.getCarParkSetResult(Development);
 await ShowCarParkRowset(rs, false);
 await Speech.Speak(rs);

}
------------------
public static async Task Speak(string text)
 {
 await Initialize();
 await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync("Welcome to Get A Lot.");
 await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync("Searching.. ");
 await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(text);
 }
```

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue. Have you tested both in the emulator and on an actual device?

Comment: It is actually on an emulator.  As of now, I do not have a wp8 device to test.

Comment: I have added the calling code and a temporary workaround.  The workaround is to insert dummy 'placeholders' which will be speech that will not be heard because of the delayed output.  In the above workaround, I hear "Searching, <text>" and sometimes "ing, <text>".  Not perfect but at least I have the whole sentence of my text.

Comment: I have tried to disable the 2 await calls (getCarParkSetResult and ShowCarParkRowset) before the speech but there is no difference.  I do have a background agent; but I have disabled that too and there is no improvement.